# Object expressions, Multiple supertype specification syntax?

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin. I came across the [Object Expressions section](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html) of https://kotlinlang.org

Some of the object expression syntaxes are very straight forward to understand,

***Create an object of an anonymous class***

```
window.addMouseListener(object : MouseAdapter() {
    override fun mouseClicked(e: MouseEvent) { ... }

    override fun mouseEntered(e: MouseEvent) { ... }
})
```

***Just an object***

```
fun foo() {
    val adHoc = object {
        var x: Int = 0
        var y: Int = 0
    }
    print(adHoc.x + adHoc.y)
}
```

But I am unable to understand the ***"Object expression with multiple supertypes specified"*** example given as below:

```
open class A(x: Int) {
    public open val y: Int = x
}

interface B { ... }

val ab: A = object : A(1), B {
    override val y = 15
}
```

What's happening here?

`${ab.y}` prints `15`
 but syntax -> `${ab.A.y}` is not valid. My understanding of `${ab.A.y}` it will print `1` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line here:

```
val ab: A = object : A(1), B {
```

means that the class of `ab` is inherited from class `A` and implements interface `B`.

Actually the code example you gave will only compile if you declare and implement the interface. This is a possible implementation:

```
open class A(x: Int) {
    public open val y: Int = x
}

interface B {
    fun hi()
}

val ab: A = object : A(1), B {
    override val y = 15

    override fun hi() {
        println("hi")
    }
}
```

The expression `${ab.A.y}` does not make much sense in this context, because the object `ab` does not have any field `A`. `A` is just the inherited superclass to which you could eventually cast.

Comment: Got it, `ab` has inherited `y` from A and then `ab` specifies `B` implementation where it overrides `A`s open variable `y`. They should have added something in `B` to be `open` for better understanding like you did. Empty `B` caused this misunderstanding, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It basically creates object `ab` with **class type A** with implementation of **interface B**.

So, let's say your class A has some method `foo()` & interface B has some method `bar()`, you can access them both on object `ab` as it's of class type `A` with implementation of `B`.

Hence, here you override variable y with value **15** meaning your superclass variable y will get overridden by value **15** from **1**.